# rda() using conditional or constrained factor/ordered variables in data frames

Tags: r, vegan

I have an environmental dataset which is mixed data (factored, ordered and numerical). I would like to use the following entry method for the `rda()` function:

```
rda(X= Community, Y=Constrained, Z= Conditional)
```

However, if I enter all 3 data frames this way they need to be matrices. I do not want to transform the Constrained or Conditional data frames into matrices, since I have factored and ordered data within them. The only other way I found to enter them in the correct format was to decompose them individually into all their vectors. This works if you're doing it manually, but I need to iterate through several Conditional and Constrained data frames. Does anybody have any ideas?

An example:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)

rda(dune ~ dune.env$A1 + dune.env$Moisture + dune.env$Management + 
    Condition(dune.env$Use + dune.env$Manure))
```

This is what I want to do, but it's long to do and very hard to write code to iterate through sets of data

```
rda(X=dune, Y=dune.env[,1:3], Z=dune.env[,4:5])
```

If this were possible it would be great, since I could put my constrained variable in one data frame and my conditional in another, but they have to be matrices, which messes up the ordered and factor variables.

Thanks a lot for the help

Rob

Answer (score 1):

`rda()` will take data frames when called in the `rda(X, Y, Z)` mode. The arguments in `?rda` take about a community data matrix but a data frame is acceptable and even assumed as we convert those inputs via `as.matrix()` and therein lies the problem.

You `rda()` call with the formula is silly. There is a `data` argument so you can do:

```
rda(dune ~ A1 + Moisture + Management + Condition(Use + Manure), data = dune.env)
```

which is somewhat easier and less verbose.

You can also take short cuts,

```
rda(dune ~ . + Condition(Use + Manure), data = dune.env)
```

by making use of `.` and only have in the data object those variables needed for the model fit.

And you can do this by getting R to build the formula for you.

```
nams <- names(dune.env)
form <- formula(paste("dune ~", paste(nams[1:3], collapse = " + "),
                      "+ Condition(", paste(nams[4:5], collapse = " + "), ")"))
rda(form, data = dune.env)
```

Whilst this might seem complex, it could easily be wrapped into a function:

```
buildF <- function(X, Y, Z, data) {
  nams <- names(data)
  X <- deparse(substitute(X))
  f <- formula(paste(X, " ~", paste(nams[Y], collapse = " + "),
               "+ Condition(", paste(nams[Z], collapse = " + "), ")"))
  environment(f) <- parent.frame()
  f
}
```

which in use gives:

```
> buildF(dune, 1:3, 4:5, data = dune.env)
dune ~ A1 + Moisture + Management + Condition(Use + Manure)
> f <- buildF(dune, 1:3, 4:5, data = dune.env)
> f
dune ~ A1 + Moisture + Management + Condition(Use + Manure)
> rda(f, data = dune.env)
Call: rda(formula = dune ~ A1 + Moisture + Management +
Condition(Use + Manure), data = dune.env)

              Inertia Proportion Rank
Total         84.1237     1.0000     
Conditional   35.3628     0.4204    6
Constrained   27.8434     0.3310    6
Unconstrained 20.9175     0.2487    7
Inertia is variance 
Some constraints were aliased because they were collinear (redundant)

Eigenvalues for constrained axes:
  RDA1   RDA2   RDA3   RDA4   RDA5   RDA6 
14.674  4.718  2.756  2.346  2.085  1.265 

Eigenvalues for unconstrained axes:
   PC1    PC2    PC3    PC4    PC5    PC6    PC7 
6.6269 4.3091 3.5491 2.5465 2.3403 0.9335 0.6121
```

[which is exactly the same as the other `rda()` outputs, not shown.]

Comment: Is it neccessary to add ordered variables as a condition or can their effect also be estimated by simply adding them to the formula like species ~ continuous_1 + continuous_2 + ordered_1?

Comment: No, it is not necessary; you can use them in the formula as constraints like any the continuous variables I used above.